# existential search and query without the fuss

Tags: algorithm, search, haskell, logic

Is there an extensible, efficient way to write existential statements in Haskell without implementing an embedded logic programming language? Oftentimes when I'm implementing algorithms, I want to express existentially quantified first-order statements like

```
∃x.∃y.x,y ∈ xs ∧ x ≠ y ∧ p x y
```

where `∈` is overloaded on lists. If I'm in a hurry, I might write perspicuous code that looks like

```
find p []     = False
find p (x:xs) = any (\y -> x /= y && (p x y || p y x)) xs || find p xs
```

or

```
find p xs = or [ x /= y && (p x y || p y x) | x <- xs, y <- xs]
```

But this approach doesn't generalize well to queries returning values or predicates or functions of multiple arities. For instance, even a simple statement like

```
∃x.∃y.x,y,z ∈ xs ∧ x ≠ y ≠ z ∧ f x y z = g x y z
```

requires writing another search procedure. And this means a considerable amount of boilerplate code. Of course, languages like `Curry` or `Prolog` that implement narrowing or a resolution engine allow the programmer to write statements like:

```
find(p,xs,z) = x ∈ xs & y ∈ xs & x =/= y & f x y =:= g x y =:= z
```

to abuse the notation considerably, which performs both a search and returns a value. This problem arises often when implementing formally specified algorithms, and is often solved by combinations of functions like `fmap`, `foldr`, and `mapAccum`, but mostly explicit recursion. Is there a more general and efficient, or just general and expressive, way to write code like this in Haskell?

Comment: I suspect that http://hackage.haskell.org/package/logict is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a standard transformation that allows you to convert

```
∃x ∈ xs : P
```

to

```
exists (\x -> P) xs
```

If you need to produce a witness you can use `find` instead of `exists`.

The real nuisance of doing this kind of abstraction in Haskell as opposed to a logic language is that you really *must* pass the "universe" set `xs` as a parameter.  I believe this is what brings in the "fuss" to which you refer in your title.

Of course you can, if you prefer, stuff the universal set (through which you are searching) into a monad.  Then you can define your own versions of `exists` or `find` to work with the monadic state.  To make it efficient, you can try [Control.Monad.Logic](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/logict/0.5.0/doc/html/Control-Monad-Logic.html), but it may involve breaking your head against Oleg's papers.

Anyway, the classic encoding is to replace all binding constructs, including existential and universal quantifiers, with lambdas, and proceed with appropriate function calls.  My experience is that this encoding works even for complex nested queries with a lot of structure, but that it always feels clunky.

Comment: Yes, I think that the LogicT monad is what I'm looking for. Thank you for responding. I'm familiar with the representation you refer to, and also find it cumbersome.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I don't understand something, but what's wrong with list comprehensions? Your second example becomes:

```
[(x,y,z) | x <- xs, y <- xs, z <- xs
, x /= y && y /= z && x /= z 
, (p1 x y z) == (p2 x y z)]
```

This allows you to return values; to check if the formula is satisfied, just use `null` (it won't evaluate more than needed because of laziness).

Comment: The problem with this implementation is that if `p1 x y z == p2 x y z` when `x == xs !! 1` and `xs` is infinite `find` will never terminate. That is why `LogicT` implements `msplit` and 'fair disjunction' `interleave `